# How to define a function that will produce the calling function's full invocation

Tags: javascript, arguments

I want to define a logging function that I can call from inside other functions. The logging function should print the full invocation of the calling function. For example:

```
function logger() {}

function F(obj1, obj2) {
    logger();
}
F('foo', {bar: 'baz'});   // console output: F('foo', {bar: 'baz'})
```

I have come close to this with the following logger:

```
function logger(args) {
    // Here the arguments objects holds the arguments passed to the
    // logger function, not the calling function.
    // We use it to get the calling function's name.
    let invocation = arguments.callee.caller.toString()
        .match(/function ([^\(]+)/)[1];

    // invocation === name of calling function

    // The arguments object from the calling function is passed
    // in as args in order to get the arguments passed with the 
    // calling function.
    let argArray = Array.from(args, function (obj) {
        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    });

    invocation += `(${argArray.join(', ')})`;
    console.log(invocation);  // Works as intended
}
```

This works, but I have to pass in the arguments parameter to the logger function every time:

```
function F(obj1, obj2) {
    logger(arguments);
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the repetition of always supplying the arguments parameter to the logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was very close to you answer:

```
function logger() {
    // Here the arguments objects holds the arguments passed to the
    // logger function, not the calling function.
    // We use it to get the calling function's name.
    let invocation = arguments.callee.caller.toString().match(/function ([^\(]+)/)[1];

    // invocation === name of calling function
    // The arguments object from the calling function is passed
    // in as args in order to get the arguments passed with the 
    // calling function.
    // Here how you can get the caller args - arguments.callee.caller.arguments
    let argArray = Array.from(arguments.callee.caller.arguments, 
        function (obj) {
            //Passed function can't be stringified, so by default they 
            //return empty string and you can just try to get the name or 
            //make a check if arg is a function object
            return JSON.stringify(obj) || obj.name;
        });

    invocation += `(${argArray.join(', ')})`;
    console.log(invocation);  // Works as intended
}

function F(obj1, obj2) {
    logger(arguments);
}

// console output: F('foo', {bar: 'baz'}, test);
F('foo', {bar: 'baz'}, function test() {});
```

By the way, be notified, that all this stuff won't work under strict mode, because any 'callee' methods are forbidden there.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick, it makes sense, and thanks for the warning as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of function currying. Refer to the below example.

```
function multiplication(a, b) {

    return a*b;

}

var multiplesOfTwo = multiplication.bind(this, 2);  // function currying
console.log(multiplesOfTwo(3));
console.log(multiplesOfTwo(5));
```

The multiplicand is always 2. The above implementation will avoid passing 2 on every call.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that would work for binding the arguments parameter. I want the logger function to get the arguments object as it exists when logger is called, not inside logger, and not at the point at which I would bind. Thinking about this is stretching my understanding of javascript variables as references to objects.

Comment: I tested briefly and it seems to work. I'll accept your answer once I understand why it works. I'm reading about 'bind' and 'this'.

Comment: I tested further and found that the value bound was in fact equal to the value of arguments at the point of binding, which unfortunately does not help.